# Check if a particular sequence of array elements is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
["Order", "Id", "Comment", "Id_type", "UbAction", "Ub_Factor", "LbAction","Lb_Factor", 
"6", "12321", "3rd test", "Industry", "0.23", "true", "0", "false", 
"22", "sss", "4", "Sector", "0", "true", "0.565676", "true",
"99", "277906", "", "Sector", "1", "true", "0", "true", 
"3", "416921", "correction check", "Industry", "1", "true", "0", "false"]
```

I have this array shown above. The first eight elements are the header. So I will remove those using splice.

I need to check if the elements `8,16,24`  AND `9,17,25` AND  `11,19,27` are empty. How can i loop through this elements dynamically. The sequence of elements are weird. Can someone please suggest how to check if these above element number is the current one which is being looped.

Comment: Correction. 8,16,24 AND 9,17,25 AND 11,19,27. These elements correspond to the Order, Id and Id_type of my grid data. Hence the sequence....

Comment: Before I go on this particular catacomb of logic, any consideration to using a JavaScript `object` (`{}` braces) rather than an array for this kind of info? Also; if you want to add information to your question, you can always Edit it.

Comment: put the ones you want to check in an array e.g. `var empty=[8,16,24,..]` then loop through that array and check, e.g. `for (var i=0,l=empty.length;i<l;i++) { if (mainArray[empty[i]])=="" /*or "0" or whatever you count as 'empty' */)  { /* do something */ }`

Comment: Since I found it interesting for the heck of it, https://oeis.org/A047472

Comment: Is there a reason why you have all this in a single 1-D array instead of an array of objects or at least a 2D array? Also, by `8,16,24...` I assume you mean indexes, your question might be clearer if you stated that, and what do you mean by empty? What's empty? An empty string? null? undefined? All of the above?

Comment: I get the data like this from the jqwidgets. Its in an array form all jumbled together in a single array.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for the replies. I worked on it a bit and the below code worked for me pretty nicely...

```
var count = 0;
var array2= [0,1,3,4,6];

function checkArray5(cell_data){
    for(var i=8;i<cell_data.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0;j<5;j++)
        { 
            if (i%8 == array2[j])
            {
                if(cell_data[i] ==="") {
                    console.log(count++);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

checkArray5(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
var myArr = ["Order", "Id", "Comment", "Id_type", "UbAction", "Ub_Factor", "LbAction", "Lb_Factor",
    "6", "12321", "3rd test", "Industry", "0.23", "true", "0", "false",
    "22", "sss", "4", "Sector", "0", "true", "0.565676", "true",
    "99", "277906", "", "Sector", "1", "true", "0", "true",
    "3", "416921", "correction check", "Industry", "1", "true", "0", "false"];
// added or remove elements to be checked if empty.
var emptyElementChk = [8, 9, 11, 16, 17, 19, 24, 25, 27];

for (var i = 0; i < emptyElementChk.length; i++) {
    //All checked array listed
    console.log("Key : " + emptyElementChk[i] + " value: " + myArr[emptyElementChk[i]]);
    if (myArr[emptyElementChk[i]] == "") {
        // empty arrays action
    } else {
        // none empty arrays action
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `%` operator to search for the indexes that return 0, 1 and 3 respectively:

```
var table = ["Order", "Id", "Comment", "Id_type", "UbAction", "Ub_Factor", "LbAction","Lb_Factor", 
"6", "12321", "3rd test", "Industry", "0.23", "true", "0", "false", 
"22", "sss", "4", "Sector", "0", "true", "0.565676", "true",
"99", "277906", "", "Sector", "1", "true", "0", "true", 
"3", "416921", "correction check", "Industry", "1", "true", "0", "false"];
var index = 0;
var columns = 8;
var cells = table.slice(columns);
var len = cells.length;

for (;index < len; index++) {
  var mod = index % columns;
  switch (mod) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 3:
     isEmpty(cells[index]);
    break;
  }
}
```